# How Can I Delete My Scrollbar? (my site doesnt fit to screen)

Tags: css

How can i fit my website to screen and get rid of scrollbar? I tried these codes but it didn't help. It just hided scrollbar, didn't help to fit my website to screen.

```
position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
```

Please help me

website: www.ubuz.net

Comment: Try: `overflow: hidden`

Comment: Sorry i forgot to write this. I tried this too.

Comment: show us your code or a demo with basic layout..

Comment: @CodeRomeos I tried, it worked but the div which is bottom of site got disappearied. (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: @G.L.P which file should give you? index.html?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit :** You need to use media screen to make your website fits in all devices ie; responsive.

You have set the position relative in this class. set it to fixed.

```
.demoDark{
position:fixed; /*Set it to fixed*/
width:100%;
height: 100%; /*semicolon missing*/
color:#eee;
margin-top:3.7em;
padding-top:3.7em;
background:#23334e url('../img/footer.png');
-webkit-box-shadow:0 -1px rgba(255,255,255,.4),0 0 50px rgba(33,49,75,.55),inset 0 4px 2px -3px rgba(0,0,0,1);
-moz-box-shadow:0 -1px rgba(255,255,255,.4),0 0 50px rgba(33,49,75,.55),inset 0 4px 2px -3px rgba(0,0,0,1);
-ms-box-shadow:0 -1px rgba(255,255,255,.4),0 0 50px rgba(33,49,75,.55),inset 0 4px 2px -3px rgba(0,0,0,1);
-o-box-shadow:0 -1px rgba(255,255,255,.4),0 0 50px rgba(33,49,75,.55),inset 0 4px 2px -3px rgba(0,0,0,1);
box-shadow:0 -1px rgba(255,255,255,.4),0 0 50px rgba(33,49,75,.55),inset 0 4px 2px -3px rgba(0,0,0,1);
```

}

Comment: Yeah I tried, it worked but the div which is bottom of site got disappearied.

Comment: @Nihat To make your website responsive, you need to use media screen. You may try using it for all standard viewports.

Comment: what is media screen i searched it but i couldnt understand what should i write to my code :(

Comment: By using media queries you can set the layout of a web-pages  in certain devices like desktop, tab, moblies..  Read and learn more : http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce the padding bottom value like this to get desired result:

```
.demoDark {
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 1.7em !important; /*reduced padding value here */
}
```

This is for wide screen only. You need to create responsive layout for hiding scroll bar from all screens. you can search and lot of articles available for creating responsive web sites.

All the best!

Comment: you are welcome.. its fine, only in small resolutions, the bottom navigation get hidden

Answer (score 0):

Add these style on your bottom div (class="alt")

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: transparent;
```